# Unable to delete directory when Invoking Ant only on slave node

Tags: jenkins, ant

Build failed on slave server only due to unable to delete only Jar directory.

We are trying to load balance the Jenkins and hence launch the slave node, where we mounted workspace of Master to slave node. We are getting the following error while doing ant clean from the /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TEST/. However, this is working fine on Master and giving error only on Slave node. Tried upgrading ant version on Slave but no luck. Also check permission and its fine. How can i solve this.

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TEST/build.xml:115: Unable to delete directory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TEST/jar
```

Adding to it if there are files inside Jar then only it fails. However, if Jar is empty then it works fine.

Comment: Has to be a permissions issue. Are you absolutely certain that user that runs the slave process is the same as the owner of the "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TEST" directory.

Comment: Yes, Tried manually as well with the same user, but giving the same error. Actually we are not using jenkins default user. Replace this default user with some another user and given the permission of same as jenkins user.  Moreover, it works perfectly fine on Master node, only slave node creates this issue.